# Request.Url.Host возвращает IP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

У меня ASP.NET MVC сайт, пытаюсь делать 301 редирект, но Request.Url.Host возвращает мне IP. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

```
 if (!Request.Url.Host.StartsWith("www") && !Request.Url.IsLoopback)
 {    
    UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
    builder.Host = "www." + Request.Url.Host;
    Response.StatusCode = 301;
    Response.AddHeader("Location", builder.ToString());
    Response.End();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyController");
```

или ему [подобные методы](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirect(v=vs.118).aspx), которые есть в MVC